# How to use Origami with Windows?

Tags: sublimetext2, origami

I'm trying to use [Origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami), but I have a problem.

The shortcut keys on Origami don't work with my computer because I have Windows (yet it claims to work on Windows)

The problem is that Origami relies on shortcut keys involving the `Windows` key,

ie.

super + k

The problem is that all of these shortcuts are already reserved by Windows. For example, `super + k` brings up the second screen panel. And `super + r` brings up `RUN`.

So how do I use Origami in a Windows environment?

Comment: Super its a OSX key, so it seems like you are reading [OSX keybindings](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami/blob/master/Default%20%28OSX%29.sublime-keymap) and not [Windows keybindings](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami/blob/master/Default%20%28Windows%29.sublime-keymap)

Answer (score 3):

I just installed this and tested it on my work comp (Windows 7) and all shortcuts work, they use `ctrl`.

To see the shortcuts, use `ctrl` + `shift` + `P`, type `Origami` and it will list all shortcuts. You will see that they are all done with the `ctrl` key.